# Would you recommend a lookup table for this situation?

Tags: mysql, database-design

This is a simplified version of my database, with the actual problem applied to a different subject area.

I have four tables: Libraries, Books, Keepers, and another table, Keepers_Sections_Permissions, that tracks which Sections a Keeper can work in. Sections are predefined, and the number of them are known ahead of time. Let's call them Science, Math, and English.

Libraries have Books (no surprise there), with each Book storing a reference to which Section it is in.

My question is, do I need a Sections table? Every library has the same Sections, with the same name. They are known ahead of time, so I won't need to populate them from my database.

Keepers_Sections_Permissions needs to reference the Section somehow, so I'm not sure if my primary key should be the name of the Section, or a unique number pointing to a Sections table (a lookup table, really).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, do I need a Sections table?

You make it sound like a good use-case for an enum, but...

> Every library has the same Sections, with the same name.

Sorry, but no. They just don't. Or maybe US libraries do; bookstores on this side of the Atlantic certainly don't.

Comment: Like I said, this is just a simplified version of my problem. For the sake of analogy, let's just assume that I **do** know every Section name :)

Comment: In that case yes, do go for an enum. But again, using a lookup table will eventually become useful because the stuff is inconsistent from a library to the next.

Comment: Thank you! Do think performance/size will be of a concern? In my case, the largest value I can expect will be 13 characters long.

Comment: Use the ID to query against it. Surely your 200-500 rows fit in APC/Memcache or equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes. It would make the system more scalable to have the sections defined in a separate table and will benefit the Keepers_Sections_Permissions table.

Comment: Would you recommend a lookup table, or should each entry in the Sections table be dependent on a Library (i.e. have a Library_id column)

Comment: Personally I would go for a lookup table and then you wont have x amount of 'Math' records for each library. Math is Math so why define it multiple times?

Comment: My last comment sounds rude... it was meant as a rhetorical question :)

Comment: Haha, no, I understand :). I was using something like that previously, and I asked myself the same question.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but, as I consider my options, think that I will go with Denis' answer. The lookup table, in my case, seems like it will be more of a hindrance. Thank you again, though.